# Get checkbox selected value from list view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, kendo-mobile

Below is my code,where i am binding weekdays inside the ul, i am using listview and template,its working fine,but i need to get the value when checkbox is selected need help, checkbox can be selected multiple so i can have multiple values

```
   <div data-role="view">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-template="script-id" data-source="listData"></ul>
    <script id="script-id" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkclass"   />
             <h3 class="checkclass">#: week #</h3>

        </div>
    </script>
    </div>

//data to bind list template
  var listData = [{ week: 'Monday' },
               { week: 'Tuesday' },
               { week: 'Saturday ', },
               { week: 'Sunday', }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register listeners with `on()` method. So in your case:

```
$(".checkboxclass").on("change", function(){
   if(this.checked) {
        $(this).val();
    }
})
```

Comment: @thanks,but i am getting error like near this.val() " Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function "

Comment: yeah now its not giving me any error but the value is giving me has "On" in value

Comment: Because you haven't defined values. Do it like this: <input type="checkbox" class="checkclass" value="1" />

Comment: yes how i can define language inside the check box value can u just help me and checkbox value should be dynamically binding

Comment: Please paste the code how you are creating checkboxes.

Comment: "http://jsbin.com/obajih/11/edit?html,js,output" i am using from this link